# Send parameter to an already open foxpro program

Tags: parameters, window, instance, foxpro

I have a program I've made in Visual FoxPro and I can open it with a parameter. 
My shortcut properties:

```
Target:   C:\Data\test.exe "5035246"
```

That opens up my program and opens up a form I've created and shows me info for ID 5035246.

Now if I want to open it up with a different ID shortcut (while the first window is still open) it opens up another instance of the program, what I want is to open it up in my already open program (and later change displaying ID in my form).

So how can I send a parameter to my already open program?

edit: I have found some code that checks if another instance of my exe is running and if so it quits, but that does not solve my other question; pass parameter to my open program.

Comment: Are you using VFP 9 for this program? If so, you can use `BINDEVENT` to handle a regular window message on the form, sent from any other program.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send multiple signals to an executing Foxpro program from an outside source, you need to either utilize COM to reference the object, or you can instead use an intermediary data store (dbf, txt file) that your program checks on a regular basis.

The best solution, if you have to use FoxPro, is to have a commmand-line program whose only job is to accept arguments, obtain a refernce to a seperate, main exe, and send its programs.  Something like the following:

```
PARAMETERS tcArg
oApp = GETOBJECT("yourApp.mainClass")
oApp.sendArg(M.tcArg)
```

Comment: Or run the program as a service and implement sockets.

Comment: @AlanB: Can you elaborate on what you mean?  A link to MSDN would not be inappropriate.

Comment: Hi! Sorry for the late reply and thanks for your answers. I will look into your possible solution DougM with the command-line program.